# OData Alternate Key configuration with aspnet core 3.1 endpoint routing

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to configure an ODATA alternate Key, while using ODATA V7, Aspnet Core 3.1, and endpoint routing. It seems I have missed a configuration step somewhere.

I think that I need to configure an AlternateKeysODataUriResolver, but with endpoint routing I haven't found where I need to do this.

My code is as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{


    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
        endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(20);
        endpoints.MapODataRoute("api", "api", GetEdmModel());
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
}

IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var odataBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<DatabaseClaim>("DatabaseClaims");
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<EmployeeClaim>("EmployeeClaims");
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Employee>("Employees");
    odataBuilder.EntitySet<Department>("Departments");

    var model = odataBuilder.GetEdmModel();

    //Add alternate key: find entity type, find property, add alternate key def
    IEdmEntityType employeeType = model.FindDeclaredEntitySet("Employees").EntityType();
    var userid = employeeType.FindProperty("UserId");
    ((EdmModel)model).AddAlternateKeyAnnotation(employeeType, new Dictionary<string, IEdmProperty> {
        {
            "UserId", userid
        }
    });

    return model;
}
```

Then in my odata controller I have

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Guid id)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    };

    var record = await Context.Employees.FindAsync(id);
    if (record == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(record);
}

[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("Employees(UserId={userid})")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByUserId([FromODataUri] string userid)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    };

    var record = await Context.Employees
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.UserId == userid);
    if (record == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(record);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Scott

Hope the following code can help you?

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
            ...
            endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata",
                    builder =>
                        builder.AddService(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => model)
                            .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp =>
                                ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", configuration))
                            .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model)));
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's getting me closer but I am stuck on the configuration parameter, is this a IRouteBuilder and where do I get an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sam Xu answer goes in the right direction you have to map the OData route like this, but it can't work because you have no HttpConfiguration (the configuration variable).

For endpoint routing use `endpoints.ServiceProvider` instead.

I have written an example for you here:

```
var model = GetEdmModel();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...
    endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder => builder
        .AddDefaultODataServices()
        .AddService(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => model)
        .AddService<IEnumerable<IODataRoutingConvention>>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, sp => ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefaultWithAttributeRouting("odata", endpoints.ServiceProvider))
        .AddService<ODataUriResolver>(Microsoft.OData.ServiceLifetime.Singleton, s => new AlternateKeysODataUriResolver(model) { EnableCaseInsensitive = true })
    );
});
```

Note that I additionally set `EnableCaseInsensitive = true` in the ODataUriResolver to use case insensitive route prefixes.